# How can I search for a null value in Orchestrate?

Tags: orchestrate

I'm trying to figure out how I can query for a non-existent or null value key in Orchestrate. This doesn't return any results:

db.search('events', 'value.originalDocument: null')

In the dashboard, I can see the key is there, and has a null value.